# Testing suspending function - no tests were found (sometimes)

Tags: kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines, rsocket

I'm having trouble understanding a strange behavior when trying to test my suspending Spring Kotlin @Controller function:

```
@Controller
class PersonRSocketController(val personRepository: PersonRepository) {
    private val sharedFlow = flow<Person> {
        for (i in 1..1000) {
               emit(Person(i.toLong(), firstName = "$i - firstName", lastName = "$i - lastName"))
        }
    }.buffer(100).shareIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(replayExpirationMillis = 0),replay = 0)

    @MessageMapping("currentpersons")
    suspend fun currentPersons(): Flow<Person?> {
        return sharedFlow
    }

}
```

Test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RsocketServerAppTests @Autowired constructor(
    val rSocketRequesterBuilder: RSocketRequester.Builder,
    @LocalServerPort val serverPort: Int
) {
    @Test
    fun testRSocket() = runBlocking{
        val requestSpec =
            rSocketRequesterBuilder.websocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:$serverPort/rsocket")).route("currentpersons")
        var result = requestSpec.retrieveFlow<PersonDataRequest>()
        assertThat(result.first().firstName).isEqualTo("1 - firstName")
//      for (i in 1..2) {
//
//      }
    }

}
```

When I run the test the test is not run - Maven reports that no tests were found.
When I uncomment the for-loop the test will run and pass. when I replace the for-loop with a `println("")` the test will also run and pass. When I replace it with `assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1)` the test will not run.
Can somebody explain this?

Comment: have you tried using `runBlockingTest()`? [Here's](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/run-blocking-test.html) the package.

Comment: Then I get the infamous " IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet"

Comment: what about including a rule to convert all functions synchronous.  The one for android architecture components is
`@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test is not discovered by JUnit whenever its return type is not `void`.
See [JUnit test methods can't return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654124/junit-test-methods-cant-return-a-value). I think this is quite unfortunate for the issue I came across.